# CodeIgniter URLs File not found on Linux Apache2

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

Cannot get my controllers working on Linux apache2 (transferred from WAMP)

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.domain.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**apache2 log**

```
[Tue Sep 23 03:36:08 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] File does not exist: /var/www/subdomain.domain.com/execute
```

**apache2 conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.domain.com

    <Directory /var/www/subdomain.domain.com>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks           
            AllowOverride All 
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Unsure what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your .htaccess file to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In your config file, try this:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

That might fix you up.

Comment: This was the answer. Thank you. Specifically the 'RewriteBase /' entry in the .htaccess.