# why isn't my mod_rewrite working even when it is enabled?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

In my phpinfo() command it shows mod_rewrite is enabled, yet i'm still getting apache's default not found page instead of my own "404" page.  Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test_modrw.php
```

Here is the section in phpinfo that shows mod_rewrite is enabled:

[image]

**EDIT**

Thanks Agama.  But still one issue, I can still directly access files in the root.  For example:

```
example.com/test_file.php
```

Can still be accessed instead of the .htaccess routing everything to index.php which is also in the root.  Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT**

Can you guys upvote this question as well as others of mine?  S.O. has banned me because they think my questions are of low-quality because of little upvotes.

Comment: have you updated the Apache conf file for `AllowOverride`?

Comment: Please show your virtual host config

Comment: Its in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` or `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.

Comment: @AgamBanga ok thanks here is what it shows:  <Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

Comment: @Dave2345 did it work for you?

Comment: @JeremyHarris where is this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the conf as below to allow the access in your `/etc/apache2/sites-available` or `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Comment: @JeremyHarris Thanks

Comment: yes, you need to allow it in `<Directory "/var/www/html">`

Comment: ok i changed accordingly, but still didn't fix it.  I'm still getting apache's default error page.

Comment: did you restart the service?

Comment: _Aside:_ I wouldn't enable `MultiViews` unless you specifically need it. It often causes problems for users of mod_rewrite when _hiding file extensions_ etc.

Comment: @AgamBanga  how did you know it was suppose to allowed in apache conf file?  i would've never guessed.

Comment: @ ya thats the problem with linux and its programs, everything is done thru trial/error, no theory or structure or rules to follow.  It's always trial and error.

Comment: @AgamBanga Heya, i can still access files directly in root but i want my .htaccess to route everything to index.php, why is that?  please if you can see my edit.

Comment: i haven't tested this but you can try adding this in your .htaccess file `<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>`

Comment: @AgamBanga awesome, it stopped direct access to files other than index.php but it still shows apache's default error page instead of my codeigniter's not found page error.  I basically want everything to route to index.php via .htaccess.

Comment: can you try this solution. i haven't worked with CI. it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986513/codeignitor-urls-file-not-found-on-linux-apache2

Comment: @AgamBanga and i can still access anything other than index.php and other .php files.

Comment: @AgamBanga ok thanks.  but can you upvote my question, they banned me for questions that don't have many upvotes.

Comment: Recommending to activate `Multiviews` to enable rewrite rules is wrong. `Indexes` is highly dubious too.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer would be to check that `AllowOverride` is set to `all` and not `none` in the necessary `<Directory>` directive (find the one that corresponds to files you serve). Just be conscious it will enable your `.htaccess` files to override a lot of options from the config.

Only do that if you know what you are doing (aka, don't do that on a server where other users can upload files as they might be able to change some options that you don't want changed). If you're the only one hosting sites on this server, all good.

If you're conscious about security and/or what other users can do, for the purpose of rewriting things, you could just change `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride FileInfo Options`

`FileInfo` will enable the rewrite rules and `Options` will enable what follows.

Then, in your `.htaccess` file, just add at the beginning:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

By doing that, you'll ensure the `FollowSymLinks` option is enabled, and `MultiViews` is disabled (as pointed out in a comment, it will cause issues with rewrites rules in certain scenario - typically, when you have double extensions like `.en.php`, `.fr.php` and `Multiviews` kicks in), no matter what the default Apache config is.

This is far better to control that on a folder/vhost basis than on the server level.

I would also highly recommend to disable `Indexes` altogether from the main config file as it's an open door to list unwanted files (basically, it shows the content of any folder that doesn't have an index file).